# Making a number input value show "∞" when the value is greater than 50

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to make function that when entered numbers cross over 50 replace field with input type text with value ∞ end when again minus 51 should reverse process to dispaly numbers. It is possible to achieve? When is infinity value I need eg hidden field with value 51 to understand data after send on server side. My dead tests below.

jquery:

```
$("#order_quantity").live("change",function() {
    var tempField;
    if($(this).val() > 50) {
        $('<input type="text"/>').val("∞").appendTo("#order_quantity");
        tempField = $('<input type="hidden" name="order[quantity]" type="number" />').val(this).appendTo("#order_quantity");
    }else{
        tempField.remove();
        $('<input name="order[quantity]" type="number" />').val(this).appendTo("#order_quantity");
        $("body").append("<br>50<br>");
    }
});
```

html:

```
<input id="order_quantity" type="number" value="1" size="30" name="order[quantity]" min="0" max="51">
```

Comment: You're appending a text input _inside_ a number input!

Comment: I guess that is why my grandma doesn't like to tell us her age.

Comment: Does ∞ really make sense for `order[quantity]`? Not to judge your business or anything, but are your stocks really that large?

Comment: I would rather put 50+ than ∞, because while +∞ > 50, +∞ does not come immediately after 50 in the number line.

Comment: I think it will be useful for different solutions and there I have given just such an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach to working around the restrictions of a number box is to conditionally show or hide a label containing a max-value indicator and the text within the input field.

Here is a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/CWq8D/

HTML:

```
Input has a max limit of 250, but displays '∞' after 50:
<input id="order_quantity" type="number" value="1" size="30" name="order[quantity]" min="0" max="250">
<br/>
Input has no max, but displays a '10+' after 10:
<input id="other_quantity" type="number" value="1" size="30" name="other[quantity]" min="0">
```

jquery.maxDisplay.js:

```
$.fn.maxDisplay = function( max, max_display ) {
  return this.each( function() {
    var $input = $( this );

    // Create a label that will position itself ontop of the input field.  The
    // label's text display will default to 'max+'.
    var $label = $('<label>');
    $label.html( max_display ? max_display : '' + max + '+')
          .css({ position : "absolute",
                 left     : "6px",
                 top      : "3px" });

    // Wrap the input in a div with relative position so that the label can be
    // positioned via absolute.
    $input.wrapAll( '<div style="position: relative;">' );

    // Insert label before the input.
    $input.before( $label );

    // Store off the input's text color.
    var color = $input.css( 'color' ); 

    function hide_label() {
      // If the label is already hidden, just return early.
      if ( !$label.is(':visible') ) return;
      $label.hide();

      // Reset the text color so that it is visible.
      $input.css({ color: color });
    };

    function show_label() {
      // If the label is already visible, just return early.
      if ( $label.is(':visible') ) return;

      $label.show();

      // The color property does not support transparent, so mimic this by
      // matching the background color.
      $input.css({ color: $input.css( 'background-color' ) });
    };

    // Control when the label is displayed.
    function display_label() {
      if ( max >=  $input.val()) {    
        hide_label()
      }
      else {
        show_label();
      }
    };

    // Invoke to set initial display.
    display_label();

    // Bind to events.
    $input.change( display_label ) // Display label based on value.
          .focus( hide_label )     // Hide label if input is focused.
          .blur( display_label );  // Hide/show label when input loses focus.

    // The label is sitting over the input field, so have its click behavior
    // mimic that of the input.
    $label.click( function() {
      hide_label();
      $input.focus();
    });
  });
};
```

And the usage:

```
// Apply max display to the input divs.
$("#order_quantity").maxDisplay( 50, "∞" );
$("#other_quantity").maxDisplay( 10 );
```

Comment: Absolutely great solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the input type to `text` might help you out ^_^

Try this out: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/dpsMa/

Code:

```
$("#order_quantity").live("change", function() {
    if (this.value > 50) {
        $(this).val("∞");
    } else if (this.value < -50) {
        $(this).val("-∞");
    } 
});
```

Comment: But the `number` type has those little up/down buttons which `text` does not.

Comment: @pimvdb yes but you cannot put a `∞` symbol in a number box.

Comment: I see that it is impossible do it like I wanted. May be possible to add html5 functionality to a text field?

Comment: nope, u cant. use some type of alerts, but no simple text in numbers and no arrows in text field